# React Native - How to update the app language dynamically with UI?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, localization, internationalization

I was trying to implement localisation in my react native app. But, I need help with one issue.

I am using following code to change my app language.

LangManager.js class

```
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import memoize from 'lodash.memoize';
import en from './locales/en.js';
import nl from './locales/nl.js';

export const translate = memoize((key, config) => i18n.t(key, config));

export const setI18nConfig = lang => {
  // fallback if no available language fits
  const fallback = { languageTag: 'en', isRTL: false };

  // clear translation cache
  translate.cache.clear();
  // update layout directio
  // set i18n-js config
  i18n.translations = { en, nl };
  i18n.locale = lang;
};

export const changeLanguage = async lang => {
  setI18nConfig(lang);
  // AsyncStorage.setItem('language', lang);
};

export const isRTL = () => {
  return translate('lang') === 'ar' ? true : false;
};
```

To use in my screen, HomeScreen.js I am using following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { translate, changeLanguage } from '../lang_manager/LangManager';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{translate('hello')}</Text>
            <Text>{translate('goodMorning')}</Text>
            <Text>{translate('currency')}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 16, padding: 16, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
                onPress={() => {
                    let count = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        console.log("en : ", count);
                        changeLanguage('en');
                    } else {
                        console.log("nl : ", count);
                        changeLanguage('nl');
                    }
                }}>
                <Text>Change Language</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

But, whenever i change my language from 'en' to 'nl' or vice versa it doesn't take effet immidiately. I need to close and start my app again to take effect or maybe setstate.

So is there any better way to update app language change take effect immidiately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it (if u use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)):

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  // replace with the screen where u changed the language
  navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('Settings')); 
);
```

[StackActions.replace](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace)

Answer (score -1):

If your app has a single screen, settingState on language change should be enough for the screen to re-render. However if you need to change the language on other screens too that have been mounted already (or even the tab bar), you will have to force a re-render on the app.

You can do that by using one of the available reloading functions. For example, if you are using Expo, you can use Updates from Expo:

```
import {Updates} from 'expo'

const HomeScreen = () => {

const {language, setLanguage} = useContext(global.LanguageContext);

  const onChangeLanguage = (value) => {
        setLanguage(value)
        changeLanguage(value)
        setTimeout(()=>Updates.reload(),500)
}

return(...)
}
```

Comment: Well, Updates will not work with react native cli. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: try this.forceUpdate();

Comment: or  react-native-restart

Comment: what is "this.forceUpdate()" and if I'm using functional component then what should i use for "this.forceUpdate()"

Comment: <Button title="Reload" onPress={() => DevSettings.reload()} />
https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload